# Does GDAL have an error with calling multiple functions on the same line of code?

Tags: python, gdal, shapefile, ogr

I typed this code on Python interpreter but the Python shell restart on the last line:

```py
from osgeo import ogr

shp_ds = ogr.Open(r'C:/Users/admin/countries.shp')
lyr = shp_ds.GetLayer(0)
#python shell restart on the following line
lyr.GetFeature(0).GetGeometryRef().GetX()
```

If I type the next lines the error doesn't occur:

```py
from osgeo import ogr

shp_ds = ogr.Open(r'C:/Users/admin/countries.shp'
lyr = shp_ds.GetLayer(0)
feature = lyr.GetFeature(0)
feature.GetGeometryRef().GetX()
```

I use GDAL 3.6.4

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a GDAL python ["gotcha"](https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html#python-crashes-if-you-use-an-object-after-deleting-an-object-it-has-a-relationship-with):

> **Python crashes if you use an object after deleting an object it has a relationship with**
>
> ...
>
> This problem can manifest itself in subtle ways. For example, it can
> occur if you try to instantiate a temporary dataset instance within a
> single line of code:
>
> ```
> from osgeo import gdal
> print(gdal.Open('C:\\RandomData.img').GetRasterBand(1).Checksum())
> <Python crashes>
> ```
>
> In this example, the dataset instance was no longer
> needed after the call to GetRasterBand() so Python deallocated it
> before calling Checksum().

The quoted example is for GDAL raster datasets, but it's the same issue with OGR.